# Integral with complex limit

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm reviewing some derivations of a formula and I faced the following step that I don't know why it is the same:

$\displaystyle \int^{i A}_{0} \frac{e^{-t}}{\sqrt{t}} \, dt =
\int^{A}_{0} \frac{ i e^{-i t}}{\sqrt{i t}} \, dt =
\frac{ (1+i) }{ \sqrt{2} }    \int^{A}_{0} \frac{e^{- i t}}{\sqrt{t}} \, dt$

I got that $\dfrac{i}{\sqrt{i}} = \dfrac{ (1+i) }{ \sqrt{2} } $ but I don't know why the exponential became complex.

Thank you.

Comment: Because the original integral is along a segment of the imaginary axis in the complex plane.

Answer (score 0):

Make the substitution $u = \dfrac{t}{i}$.  Then when $t = 0$, we have $u = 0$.  And when $t = iA$, we have $u = A$.  Also, $t = iu$ and $dt = i\,du$.  So the integral becomes:
$$
  \int_0^{iA} \frac{e^{-t}}{\sqrt{t}} \, dt = \int_0^A \frac{e^{-iu}}{\sqrt{iu}} i\,du
$$

Basically they did a $u$-substitution but they kept using the same variable.